# Ошибка при выборке данных "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Пишу службу `Windows` которая будет получать данные из БД MSSql и обрабатывать у себя.

Использую модель

```
public class СstiData
    {
        public int VEU_ID  { get; set; }
        public DateTime DT { get; set; }
        public int VALUE { get; set; }
        public int PARAM_ID { get; set; }
    }

public class CstiContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<СstiData> CstiData { get; set; } = null;
        public CstiContext(string connString)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connString;
        }

    }
```

При получении

```
var sql = @"select
              dateadd(ms, t, CONVERT(datetime, '02.28.2022')) dt,
              f.V
            from
                A28022022 f
            where
                n = 1002";
var dataList = ctx.СstiData.SqlQuery(sqlStr).ToList();
```

Получаю ошибку
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'xxxx_xxxx_DATA'."`
Мне не нужно создавать таблицу, я хотел бы получить данные по запросу. Как в этом случае использовать произвольный запрос который например связывает несколько таблиц?

Comment: Если получаете такую ошибку, значит, программа пытается выполнить запрос CREATE TABLE. Вот и разбирайтесь, по какой причине... может, таблицы нет, и модель пытается её создать?

Comment: @Akina Таблица есть, запрос в студии выполняется, данные по запросу тоже есть.

Comment: Чудес - не бывает. Если ошибка говорит, что была попытка создания таблицы, то такая попытка действительно была. Вот и разбирайтесь, почему и откуда.

Comment: @Akina я знаю, но вот такой запрос var dataList = ctx.CstiData.SqlQuery(@"select getdate() dt, 5 Value ").ToList(); выдает такую же ошибку

Comment: Я не понимаю, чего Вы от меня-то хотите? сервер - это существо ну совершенно без фантазии, и придумать, что его просили создать таблицу, когда этого не было, просто неспособен. Берите SQL Server Profiler да смотрите...

Comment: @Akina Лично от вас ничего не хочу. сервер не мой и на запуск профайлера нет прав

Comment: Я вообще-то к тому, что ТОЛЬКО ВЫ можете провести работы, которые позволят определить источник, посылающий CREATE TABLE. Никакая опубликованная в вопросе и комментариях информация не даёт даже намёка на то, почему и откуда. Потому выдать причину на основании только опубликованной информации - ну совершенно бесперспективно и безнадежно. А если нет возможности использовать профайлер - остаётся разве что использовать трассировку с пошаговым выполнением и сниффер...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @Akina  создал локально базу и запустил профайлер, т.к на удаленном не было прав на это действо. Увидел что происходит попытка миграции модели.
Проблему решил отключив ее в конструкторе контекста

```
Database.SetInitializer<CstiContext>(null);
```